# ASP.Net Identity Login Redirect Enforce Protocol (Https) Part 2 (.Net 6++)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

##### Prior reference (.Net Framework/ASP.Net MVC): [ASP.Net Identity Login Redirect Enforce Protocol (Https)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615017/asp-net-identity-login-redirect-enforce-protocol-https)

It seems this is still an "issue" in `.Net 6+`. There are cases where the return url constructed by the infrastructure results in an `http` scheme/protocol instead of `https` for oauth/external logins (Google, etc). This obviously fails because it must be `https`.

While I haven't gone deep into things, because I haven't found the source code for it (yet?), it's likely the same "issue" - at the app level, it doesn't "see" a `https` request (because SSL is offloaded somewhere) and therefore the url created "matches" the scheme/protocol, resulting in an `http` redirect url.

End of day, whatever hosting infrastrucutre/configuration my host has is in place is **beyond my control**. Therefore, the ultimate goal is to **force** `https` (hard code, skip/override whatever scheme/protocol check/eval in place).

There's nothing special in my setup and it's working fine in local/dev (https) testing. It's only when the application is finally hosted (production):

In startup `program.cs` this is the only related code I have for external login (along with the scaffolding/templates of the identity package):

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<my_db_context>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(goog =>
{
    goog.ClientId = builder.Configuration["GoogleAuthClientId"];
    goog.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["GoogleAuthClientSecret"];
});
```

The issue:

[image]

- the origin is `https`
- the redirect uri sent to Google Auth is `http` - this will **always** fail

Can anyone point me to relevant docs/source on how to add/override options in .Net 6 and above? (similar to prior implementations in .Net Framework/MVC)?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @Tratcher : THANK YOU! The option that got it to work was by explicitly/manually setting `context.Request.Scheme = "https";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the comment by @Tratcher:

Official Ref: [Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer)

Essentially: [ForwardedHeadersMiddleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.httpoverrides.forwardedheadersmiddleware)

For *my specific* case:

> In some cases, it might not be possible to add forwarded headers to
> the requests proxied to the app. If the proxy is enforcing that all
> public external requests are HTTPS, the scheme can be manually set
> before using any type of middleware:
>
> ```
> ...
>
> app.Use((context, next) => {
> context.Request.Scheme = "https";
> return next(context); });
>
> ...
> ```